# My Tkinter code is not executing before the next lines of the code

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, tkinter-text

I am trying to make a reminder in python which sends message to whatsapp.

```py
import pywhatkit
import tkinter as tk

def sendmsg():
    L1.grid_forget()
    E1.grid_forget()
    L2.grid_forget()
    E2.grid_forget()
    button.grid_forget()
    text.grid()
    text1.grid()
    text2.grid()
    text.insert(tk.END, "Reminders")
    rname = name1.get()
    tym = time1.get()
    tym1 = list(tym.split(":"))
    text1.insert(tk.END, "Name:" + rname)
    text2.insert(tk.END, "Time:" + tym)
    smth()

def smth():
    rname = name1.get()
    tym = time1.get()
    tym1 = list(tym.split(":"))
    pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91xxxxxxxxxx", "You said to remind me to " + rname, int(tym1[0]), int(tym1[1]), 10, True, 3)
    button1.grid()
r=tk.Tk()
r.title("Reminder")
name1=tk.StringVar()
time1=tk.StringVar()
r.geometry("600x400")
L1 = tk.Label(r, text="Remind me for")
E1 = tk.Entry(r, textvariable=name1)
L2 = tk.Label(r, text="Time")
E2 = tk.Entry(r, textvariable=time1)
text=tk.Text(r,height=2,borderwidth=0,font=",10")
text1=tk.Text(r,height=2,borderwidth=0)
text2=tk.Text(r,height=2,borderwidth=0)

button=tk.Button(r,text="Submit",command=sendmsg)

def dis():
    L1.grid(row=0,column=0)
    E1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    L2.grid(row=1,column=0)
    E2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    button.grid(row=2,column=1)
    button1.grid_forget()
    text.grid_forget()
    text1.grid_forget()
    text2.grid_forget()
    E1.delete(0, tk.END)
    E2.delete(0, tk.END)

button1 = tk.Button(r, text="Add new", command=dis)
button1.grid()
r.mainloop()
```

its is working fine but the reminders,name and time of the reminders is showing only after sending the message.

```
L1.grid_forget()
E1.grid_forget()
L2.grid_forget()
E2.grid_forget()
button.grid_forget()
text.grid()
text1.grid()
text2.grid()
text.insert(tk.END, "Reminders")
rname = name1.get()
tym = time1.get()
tym1 = list(tym.split(":"))
text1.insert(tk.END, "Name:" + rname)
text2.insert(tk.END, "Time:" + tym)
```

its just ignoring this code and running the smth()

I just want to remove the entries and submit button as soon as i press submit button and display the name and time of the reminder given.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could move the code that inserts the text and displays the (`text, text1 and text2`) widgets to the beginning of the `sendmsg` function, **before** calling the `smth` function?

This way, the text and widgets should be displayed before the message is sent.

```
def sendmsg():
    text.grid()
    text1.grid()
    text2.grid()
    text.insert(tk.END, "Reminders")
    rname = name1.get()
    tym = time1.get()
    tym1 = list(tym.split(":"))
    text1.insert(tk.END, "Name:" + rname)
    text2.insert(tk.END, "Time:" + tym)
    
    L1.grid_forget()
    E1.grid_forget()
    L2.grid_forget()
    E2.grid_forget()
    button.grid_forget()

    smth()
```

Comment: No It did not solve it